# Internal htaccess redirect vs direct navigation

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess redirect script for my mobile detection:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|android|nokia|BlackBerry) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^mobile/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/mobile/ [R=301,L]
```

When I get redirected to the mobile site, my links don't work that point to:

```
www.example.com/img0.jpg
```

If I navigate directly to the site by browsing to:

```
www.example.com/mobile/
```

the links work perfectly.

What am I missing in the .htaccess file that is affecting this linking?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I used your script and then added this into the mobile directory, not exactly sure why it works, but it does!

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mobile\.example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} example.com/mobile 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|android|nokia|BlackBerry) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^mobile/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/mobile/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I used your script and then added this into the mobile directory, not exactly sure why it works, but it does!    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mobile\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} http://www.example.com/mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [L]